# How to get height 100% in overflow parent

Tags: css, sass

Hellow everyone.

I have a element with two `divs` and one `father parent` how have overflow height, the left `div` have `height: 200px` and the right `div` have `height: 100%`, why the right div dont expand all content?

Im using `SCSS`, if have a alternative way I will accept the question as correct

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
  background: #09f;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left{
  background: #ef5523;
  min-height: 200px; //height size for example
}

.right{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #99ff99;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">Left List</div>
  <div class="right">Right List</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add "height: 100%" to your .main style

Comment: 100% height depends on the height of the parent element, so add 'height: ___px' to your .main element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS grid can do this:

```css
.main{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
  background: #09f;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left{
  background: #ef5523;
  height: 200px;
}

.right{
  background: #99ff99;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">Left List</div>
  <div class="right">Right List</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to alter the html in order to do this.

```css
.main{
  background: #09f;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.overflow {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.left{
  background: #ef5523;
}

.right
  background: #99ff99;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="overflow">
    <div class="left">Left List</div>
    <div class="right">Right List</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
  background: #09f;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left{
  background: #ef5523;
  height: 200px;
}

.right{
  background: #99ff99;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">Left List</div>
  <div class="right">Right List</div>
</div>
```

**strong text**
1

since you are using flex we can use flex-grow property for second div . if will take full div.no need to use 100% for second div